# Tensorflow - matmul is showing InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use matmul in tensorflow like this-

```
tf.matmul(y_true, logy)
```

where

> **y_true** = <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1000, 1, 1)

> **logy** = <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'> (1000, 1)

I am getting this error-

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1000, 1, 1)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'> (1000, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-4cc645f4bb75> in <module>()
     25   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
     26     y_predicted = h(x_train,w)
---> 27     costF = loss_function(y_predicted, y)
     28 
     29   gradients = tape.gradient(costF, w)

5 frames
<ipython-input-39-4cc645f4bb75> in loss_function(y_pred, y_true)
     18   print(type(y_true), y_true.shape)
     19   print(type(logy), logy.shape)
---> 20   p1 = tf.matmul(y_true, logy)
     21   p2 = tf.matmul(1-y_true, logyInv)
     22   return -tf.reduce_mean(p1 + p2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in matmul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, adjoint_a, adjoint_b, a_is_sparse, b_is_sparse, output_type, name)
   3606       else:
   3607         return gen_math_ops.batch_mat_mul_v2(
-> 3608             a, b, adj_x=adjoint_a, adj_y=adjoint_b, name=name)
   3609 
   3610     # Neither matmul nor sparse_matmul support adjoint, so we conjugate

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in batch_mat_mul_v2(x, y, adj_x, adj_y, name)
   1507       return _result
   1508     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 1509       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   1510     except _core._FallbackException:
   1511       pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6939   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6940   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6941   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6942   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6943 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute BatchMatMulV2 as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a int64 tensor but is a double tensor [Op:BatchMatMulV2]
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What do you think should be the result of the operation? Do you know how matrix multiplication works? In your own words, what are the constraints on the input shapes and sizes for matrix multiplication? Why?

Comment: If you don't understand that theory, then you have a math question, not a programming question. If you do understand, then you should try to work backwards to figure out which part of the code is wrong. Should you, in fact, be trying to do this `matmul`? If you should, what should the shapes of `y_true` and `logy` be instead? Now, keep working backwards to figure out why they aren't the shapes that they should be.

Comment: After you have [made an attempt yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), as is [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on Stack Overflow, then you can ask a *specific* question about the problem, showing the work that you did and the understanding that you have so far. But as it stands, you haven't shown us the code, so we can't tell you any more than "probably there is something wrong with the code".

Comment: Your account is over 8 years old and you have 20 gold badges. You are supposed to know all of this by now regarding how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Karl Knechtel already said, you have a mismatch in your shapes. Correct it and see if the error goes away.

If not, it's because you're trying to perform an operation with operands of different types (int64 and double). The message says what's wrong:
`InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute BatchMatMulV2 as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a int64 tensor but is a double tensor [Op:BatchMatMulV2]`.
It says that your first argument is **int64** and your second argument is **double**. Cast either of your arrays:

```
y_true.astype(np.double)
```

or

```
logy = tf.cast(logy, tf.int64)
```